# PostgreSQL function execution delay

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, pgadmin

So, here is my problem: i have 2 stored function, first one should run the second one, but not at the execution time. The second function should be executed as some time passes. How can i do that?

Comment: Directly with PostgreSQL you can't. PgAgent might help, but it is a separate application.

Comment: I thought about it, but didn't figure out how to run PgAgent job from PostgreSQL function.

Comment: Use `LISTEN` and `NOTIFY` with an external helper program

Comment: You could simply schedule two cron jobs. The first one executes a function with psql that writes a result to a table. The second one can take results from the first one into consideration. ***Or*** you could use `LISTEN` / `NOTIFY`  like Craig suggested, and have the listening process schedule an `at`- job (with the unix [`at` command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_%28Unix%29), (like `cron`, just for a single job).

Answer (score 1):

You can use

> pg_sleep(10)

before calling second function

Comment: This is unacceptable because calling pg_sleep sleeps the first function, so the caller has to wait for the response and waiting interval is longer than connection timeout.